# Memory allocation with reference variable in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, heap-memory

I have compiled following piece of code in **G++** compiler, it's working fine without any error or warning.

```
#include <iostream>             
int main()                      
{                               
    int &r = *(new int(100));   
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
    return 0;                   
}
```

**How does the reference variable working with memory allocation?**

**Is it valid to allocate memory for reference variable?**

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: You refer to an int. Why won't it work?! You just leak it.

Comment: `new int` allocates memory. The reference may not (and probably does not, in this case) allocate memory.

Comment: With your code you are allocating 4/8bytes of stack space for a pointer to an integer and 400 bytes (but it may be also 200 or 800, depending from your complier/OS) on the heap. When the program ends you leak the heap allocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C++ Standard (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 1 The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which
>   it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression
>   is “pointer to T”, the type of the result is “T”. [ Note: Indirection
>   through a pointer to an incomplete type (other than cv void) is valid.
>   **The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example)**; this lvalue must not be converted to a
>   prvalue, see 4.1. —end note ]

In this statement

```
int &r = *(new int(100));
```

there is declared a reference to the lvalue obtained by using the operator `*` of an unnamed object created in the heap.

Lately you can delete the object using the reference

```
delete &r;
```

Consider a more interesting example with the polymorphism.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        virtual ~A()
        {
            std::wcout << "A::~A()" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    struct B : A
    {
        ~B()
        {
            std::wcout << "B::~B()" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    A &ra = *(new B);
    delete &ra;
}
```

The program output is

```
B::~B()
A::~A()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator returns a pointer to whatever it's allocated for you. When you dereference a pointer, you get a reference to the value it points to. Simple as that.

It's been that way since C (though references weren't an explicit thing). It allows code like this:

```
void modify_my_int(int* the_int) { *the_int = 4; }

int main(void)
{
    int var;
    modify_my_int(&var);
    printf("%d\n", var); // prints "4"
}
```

Comment: I think the question was more about why the lvalue reference was allowed.